# Why is [datetime] converting this UTC time correctly and how can I replicate that with ParseExact

Tags: powershell, datetime, utc, powershell-5.1

I feel silly that I cannot figure this one out on my own.

I have dates coming from the CarbonBlack API e.g. 2022-02-15-172040 which are in UTC

The `[datetime]` type cast works fine if I remove the seconds portion of the string

```
PS M:\Scripts> [datetime]"2022-02-15-1720"   
Tuesday, February 15, 2022 12:20:00 PM
```

I don't understand how it "knows" that is a UTC string. It is correct of course but I expected 5:20pm for the time portion. I wanted the seconds for the date so I went to parse exact as this doesn't match any format strings as far as I know

```
PS M:\Scripts> [datetime]::ParseExact("2022-02-15-172040", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss" ,[Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentUICulture)
Tuesday, February 15, 2022 5:20:40 PM
```

Which is the time I expected but the incorrect time.

Why is the `[datetime]` working when I wouldn't expect it to and what do I need to do to the string or static method call for it to treat that as a UTC string with minimal manipulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because

```
([datetime]"2022-02-15-1720").Kind
```

yields '**Local**', while

```
([datetime]::ParseExact("2022-02-15-172040", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).Kind
```

returns '**Unspecified**'

If you want the result to handle the string as being **Local** time and then the result should be in **UTC**, use:

```
([datetime]::ParseExact("2022-02-15-172040", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, 'AssumeLocal')).ToUniversalTime()
```

or

```
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact("2022-02-15-172040", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
[datetime]::SpecifyKind($date, 'Local').ToUniversalTime()
```

---

Going the other way around, so if you regard the date in the string represents **UTC** (Universal Time), and you want the result to be in
**Local time** , you need to do this:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("2022-04-29-185121", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, 'AssumeUniversal')
```

Here, `ParseExact()` treats the string as UTC and outputs a date **converted to Local time**
(`.Kind` --> 'Local'), which is the exact same output as

```
[datetime]"2022-04-29-1851"
```

would give: also here, `.Kind` --> 'Local'`

If then you want the resulting date to be in UTC, you need to convert it back again with `.ToUniversalTime()`

The tricky part is that using `ParseExact()` **without** the third parameter ('AssumeLocal' or 'AssumeUniversal') when parsing a string that has no
indication of it being Local or UTC like the example strings here, is always returning a datetime object with its `.Kind` property set to **Unspecified**.

<sup>Thanks to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72059342/why-is-datetime-converting-this-utc-time-correctly-and-how-can-i-replicate-tha/72060086?noredirect=1#comment127325759_72060086)'s comment,
in PowerShell (Core) 7+, strings like in the example are no longer recognized and should have a TimeZone indication like '2022-02-15 17:20Z'. ('Z' --> Zulu (UTC) Time)</sup>

If you do give it the third parameter, telling it what timezone it should use ('AssumeLocal' or 'AssumeUniversal'), the resulting datetime object will
always have its `.Kind` property set to **Local** and the result will be converted to local time in case you have given `AssumeUniversal` as parameter.

Comment: Nicely done; note that the particular format (`'2022-02-15-1720'`) is no longer recognized in PowerShell (Core) 7+; the equivalent would be: `[datetime] '2022-02-15 17:20Z'`

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something `([datetime]::ParseExact("2022-04-29-185121", "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, 'AssumeLocal')).ToUniversalTime()` does not give me the same result as `[datetime]"2022-04-29-1851"` (ignoring the difference in seconds of course). Does it for you?

Comment: @Matt Please see my edit, I have added some more explanation.

Comment: I see now. I misinterpreted the 'AssumeLocal' to apply to the output. Not describe the input. Appreciate the extra information. I double marked as answer :)